# How to compute the difference between 2 similarity matrices?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, matrix, similarities

I had asked this question on Mathoverflow.net and someone suggested that this might be a better forum. So here is the question again
Hello, I have two n*n correlation matrices with values ranging between -1,1. (2 correlation matrix because I have the same n terms under 2 different conditions) Taking the absolute of the correlation matrix, I then transformed the correlation into a similarity matrix where values range between [0,1]. The similarity was computed using the formula here:

[image]

where lij = summation(aiu.auj) and aiu= is correlation value between ith and uth element in the correlation matrix. ki,kj in our case is n-1.

This gives me 2 similarity matrices.

My question is how can I compute the difference between the similarity matrices (SIM)? Will doing a simple abs(SIM1-SIM2) make statistical/mathematical sense? Is there a robust way to find/quantify difference between two similarity matrices?

Any ideas will be truly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Zen had a good comment in [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24944/how-to-compare-two-distance-matrices?rq=1).

Comment: There are many ways to make such comparisons, depending on the application.  What is your intended purpose?

Comment: The conditions I have are gene expression measurements from disease and normal tissue. Ideally I would like to obtain a measure of "differential" expression.